# Using a function within a select PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a function that calculates the distance between two points given the latitude and longitude of the two points:

```
my_function (lat_point1 NUMERIC, long_point1 NUMERIC, lat_point2 NUMERIC, long_point2 NUMERIC)
```

I want to use the function in a `select` to calculate the distance between my point1, which is always the same, and my point2, which has multiple values.

I have a table with 3 columns and several rows. The first column is the name of the point in the map, the second is the latitude of the place and the third one has the longitude. The rows has the different points.

The function has 4 inputs my_function(latutude_point1, longitude_point1, latutude_point2, longitude_point2).

The problem is that I need to calculate the distance between the point1 with all the others. In other words, I need to calculate the distance between the point1 with point2, point1 with point3, point1 with point4, point1 with point**n**.

How can I call the function in a select?

Comment: `select my_function(...) from ...`

Comment: yes, but how can I tell which lon and lat one is the point1 and which ones longs and lats are the point2?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: I have my points in a table. Imagine its the table tb_points that have this extructure num_point, long_point, lat_point. So the first row will be point1, 1.5641, 45.6555, the second one will be point2, 1.6895, 25.3654 and so on. I dont know how to tell the function witch points should take. I want to calcule the distance between point1 and point2, point1 and point3 ... point1 and pointn.

Comment: Calling the function will be trivial once you've got a Select that has all the colums you need. You'll likely need to call LEAD or LAG or you can use a self join. I don't know which because your question is missing some info

Comment: Question editted for better undestanding.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a `cross join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*,
       my_function(t1.lat, t1.lng, t2.lat, lt2.lng)
from t t1 cross join
     t t2;
```

You may want to include `where t1.lat <> t2.lat and t1.lng <> t2.lng` to avoid self comparisons.